# What is the best way to deserialize a json object into a list having different behavior than ArrayList

Tags: java, jackson

My REST service is accepting an object of `class A` having list of `objects B`.
The behavior of objects required is that if there is some duplicate entry the weights need to be added. Using `jackson` to serialize/deserialize
To achieve this there are 2 ways around:

1. Inherit `ArrayList` and override add method and add logic to sum weights if an entry with same name is present.
2. Using `@JsonDeserialize` while deserializing the JSON.

Which option is preferred and why?

```
class A {
  List<B> objects;
  // Getters and Setters
}

class B {
  String name;
  Float weight;
  boolean equals() {
    // compares name.
  }
}
```

Sample JSON

```
{
objects:[{name:"X", weight:10.2},{name:"Y",weight:12.5},{name:"X", weight:20}]
}
```

This should produce a list of objects with size of 2, having values as

```
name:X,weight:30.2 and name:Y,weight:12.5.
```

Comment: You can also read normally the JSON into an object of class A, and the process the list to remove duplicates and add the weights.

Comment: Option 2 is preferred; favor composition over inheritance. Inheriting from `ArrayList` and corrupt contained objects along the way is more than dodgy and just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To achieve this there are 2 ways around:
>
> 1. Inherit `ArrayList` and override add method and add logic to sum weights if an entry with same name is present.
> 2. Using `@JsonDeserialize` while deserializing the JSON.
>
> Which option is preferred and why?

You shouldn't use any of these approaches, by the way. See below:

1. Overriding the `add()` method for performing calculations should be avoided. You can take advantage of streams for processing the data that has been added to the list.
2. Jackson should be used *only for JSON parsing* and not for performing business logic.

What you should do, in fact, is receiving the JSON in your controller layer, parsing it as a list and then delegate to the service layer, where you'll perform both grouping and summing operations.

Also, it's important to mention that you must **avoid** both `Float` and `Double` types for calculations, as they have problems with precision. Use `BigDecimal` instead.

Finally, here's what your method for grouping and summing can be like with `BigDecimal`:

```java
public List<B> groupByNameAndSumWeight(List<B> list) {
    return list.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(B::getName, reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, B::getWeight, BigDecimal::add)))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> new B(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
            .collect(toList());
}
```

And just ensure you have the following static imports:

```java
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.reducing;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me like a base reason to differentiate between a controller and a service layer. Let the controller accept the pure list and hand it over to a service that does the processing.

```
@Controller class MyController {
    @Autowired MyService service;
    @PostMapping(..) void postList(@Body List<B> items) {
        service.accept(items);
    }
}
```

In the service, you can do the adding of weights.

```
@Service class MyService {
    JpaRepository<B> repository;
    public void accept(List<B> items) {
        List<B> summed = 
            items.stream().collect(groupingBy(B::getName, summarizingDouble(B::getWeight)))
             .entrySet().stream().map(e -> new B(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
             .collect(toList());
        repository.save(summed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using custom implementation for add or using @JsonDeserialize, you could process the objects list in the **service** or create an **interpreter** to process objects list.
You can add following code to process list,

```
 objects = objects.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(B::getName, Collectors.summingDouble(B::getWeight)))
            .entrySet().stream().map(ele-> new B(ele.getKey(), ele.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Hope it helps.